# Get count of divs in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a div containing several other `divs` like this:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 no-pad offersContainer">
    <div class="pan-box specialoffers"></div>
    <div class="pan-box offers"></div>
    <div class="pan-box offers"></div>
</div>
```

I want to loop through these `divs` to get `count` of all having class `pan-box`.
How can I do this?

Comment: `$('div.pan-box').length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$("div.pan-box").length will give you the number of divs having class 'pan-box'

Comment: Not exactly, it will give you all the html elements having `class="pan-box"`, not just divs.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop. Use length

```js
console.log($(".pan-box").length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 no-pad offersContainer">
    <div class="pan-box specialoffers"></div>
    <div class="pan-box offers"></div>
    <div class="pan-box offers"></div>
</div>
```